# How to rearrange a scalar product equation to make a vector the subject?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, work, vectors

Mechanical work is defined as the scalar product of force (**F**) and displacement (**s**).
I.e. W = **F**.**s**

How can this equation be rearranged to make **F** or **s** the subject?

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by making "a vector the subject".

Comment: @NDewolf I want the equation one of the vectors from the scalar product as the subject of the equation.

Comment: If I understand correctly, I think this question is getting at an interesting point, since what it asks (rewriting the equation to get an explicit expression for one of the vectors) is not possible (as my answer explains), but this is not obvious if one is not used to working with vectors. If this was indeed your question @Felix, then perhaps I can edit it to be more in line with the usual jargon.

Answer (score 0):

Inherently, the problem as posed cannot be fully solved: say you know $W$ and $\mathbf{s}$, and that $W = \mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{s}$; then you do not have enough information to recover $\mathbf{F}$, since many different vectors $\mathbf{F}$ will give the same result.
You have gained some knowledge about $\mathbf{F}$ with $W = \mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{s}$, but not the full picture (unless you are in 1 dimension).

Let us consider a simple, 2D example: suppose that $W = 1$, and $\mathbf{s} = [1, 0]^{\top}$ (the transpose is just there so that it is a column vector, you can ignore it).
What this tells you, geometrically, is that the *projection* of $\mathbf{F}$ onto $\mathbf{s}$ is equal to 1, but infinitely many vectors satisfy this property: writing out the dot product explicitly, we have
$$
1 = W = 
\left[\begin{array}{c}
F_x \\ 
F_y
\end{array}\right]\cdot
\left[\begin{array}{c}
1 \\ 
0
\end{array}\right]
= F_x\,,
$$
which means that $F_x = 1$.
There is no constraint on $F_y$: any value for it will still satisfy the required property. So, any vector in the form $\mathbf{F} = [1, F_y]^\top$ will work.

This means that you cannot turn your equation into something of the form $\mathbf{F} = \dots$, since that would mean you have a unique solution to this problem, which does not exist.

You can also think of it like this: the equation $W = \mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{s}$ is a scalar equation, it relates numbers; while if you were to write $\mathbf{F} = \dots$ that would be a vector equation, which corresponds to several, independent scalar equations (as many as the dimension of your space, so often 3).
You cannot turn one equation into several, independent ones.